# VS Code git samba, file outside repository

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, samba

Im facing a strange issue with VS Code and a got repository on a samba share.

Im working on windows and shared a raspberry pies folder (docker compose samba).

When I try to stage a file by pressing + inside the git addon I get following error:

> Git: fatal: X:/.gitignore: 'X:/.gitignore' is outside repository at
> '//IP/openhab_docker'

The repository is within the root folder of the share (X drive).

Strange thing is that when I use git add in the terminal it's working without any issues.

Any ideas? It's my first git setup

Update:
looks like when i add the git repository into a subfolder its all working fine, except git push. But moving the whole system to another subfolder is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I try to open vscode in `//IP/target_folder/.gitignore` instead of `X:/.gitignore` fix that.